# How can I monitor if the Laravel queue is running?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I can start the queue as such:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

This works fine, but I would like to monitor if the queue is running, especially important as there doesn't seem to a fallback if it's not.

To be clear, if I queue an email through a controller, like so:

```
$this->mailer->queue($view, $data, function ($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $subject) {
    $message
        ->to($toEmail, $toName)
        ->subject($subject);
    });
```

This will successfully run, but if the queue is not 'listening', the job gets pushed on to the job table, forever.

I am looking for something like `\Queue::isListening();`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, when a queue fails a `failing` event fires, so for example, you may register the `failing` event in your `AppServiceProvider` class in the `boot` method using something like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
        // $event->connectionName
        // $event->job
        // $event->data
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare a `failed` method in the `handler` class for example:

```
class SendEmail extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        //...
    }


    public function failed()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

[The Updated link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#failed-job-events).

### Regarding background monitoring, you may use [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/):

> Supervisor is a client/server system that allows its users to monitor
>   and control a number of processes on UNIX-like operating systems.

In this case, you have to install it on your machine and configure it using at least one `program` section, for example:

```
[program:queue]
command=/usr/local/bin/php artisan queue:listen --tries=3
```

This is an example of `program` section that I've used to monitor my `queue` using `Supervisord`. In this case, you need to read the documentation for the [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/running.html) to understand how to use it, I've just gave you an idea. The `supervisord` will run in the background once you start it and it'll also restart the observation even after the server is restarted (if it goes down for some reason) so you don't need to worry about that.

A simple (minimal) config file may look something like this:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/someDirName/www/example.com/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=info
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false
loglevel=warn

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock

[program:queue]
command=/usr/local/bin/php artisan queue:listen --tries=3
directory=/home/someDirName/www/example.com
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

Well, you may read the documentation to really get the clear idea about it. This may help you to start.

Comment: I see where you are going (and I am currently using supervisord) - but I wanted to basically do a health check of the system. I think I might be able to utilise your first event technique there by intentionally creating a fake queue item, and listen to see if it fails..

Comment: @Chris Have you found a solution for this? My hosting provider won't allow me to use Supervisord as it conflicts something else (don't kow what)

Comment: Not sure why this answer mentioned `failing` event which doesn't seem to be related to the question at all. If the task does not fail, failing event would never fire.

Answer (score 36):

This is lower level but in the same vein you could run a command such as `ps -aux | grep queue` to literally view the running queue processes on whatever server your application/queue workers are running on.

Comment: This deserves to be higher up, it answers the question best. Thank you!

Comment: A small improvement to exclude the command returning self:

```php
$queueProcess = Process::fromShellCommandline('ps -aux | grep -v grep | grep "php artisan queue:work"');
$queueProcess->run();
$isRunning = rescue(fn () => filled($queueProcess->getOutput()), false);
```

Comment: This answer as it is is dangerous - just because you see queue in the output doesn't mean it's for the artisan queue - in this case it will also return `grep` because you just passed "queue" as an input. The artisan queue specifically will be either `artisan queue:listen` or `artisan queue:work`.

Comment: With `pgrep -af 'queue'`, you don't get the grep process at the bottom

Answer (score 10):

Laravel 8.53 introduced a new artisan command for monitoring the queue:

```
php artisan queue:monitor redis:default
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#monitoring-your-queues

Comment: As far as I can see this just monitors the queue length.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method like you say

> \Queue::isListening();

But you can configure [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/): A process control system to look after your queue. here is a the Laravel documentation for supervisor configuation 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration